# Loud aloud loudly

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can I use "loud" "aloud" and "loudly" in this sentence?
"I don't like it when people eat loud."
Is it wrong to omit "it" in such sentences? For example, "I don't like it when my parents worry about me too much."

Comment: ***Loud*** is an adjective (modifies *nouns*, as in *I heard a loud noise*). ***Loudly*** is an adverb that's not actually used very often, but it would usually modify a *verb*, as in *He loudly protested his innocence*. Finally, adverbial ***aloud*** normally just means "not silently", as in *Please read the text aloud* (which doesn't necessarily imply speaking at ***high*** volume).

Comment: Why would "loudly" not be used very often? I can think of many contexts in which you would use it. "Argh! He was singing loudly during the pianissimo!" Or "He suddenly coughed loudly, making us all jump." It's "aloud" that has limited use.

Comment: @PrimeMover: Well, it's obvious from my definition ("aloud" just means "not silently") that there won't be *many* contexts where such a quality needs to be pointed out. But the reason I said ***loudly*** isn't used all that much is because we very often use ***loud*** as a "flat adverb". So it's invariably *There's no need to talk so **loud***, not ***...so loudly***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Not when you're speaking correct English. Just because "loud" is subject to widespread misuse does not excuse that misuse being propagated on a site dedicated to learning accurate usage.

Answer (score 4):

"Loud" is an *adjective*. "Aloud" and "loudly" are *adverbs*. Hence it is always incorrect to say "eat loud". It should therefore either be "eat loudly" or "eat aloud."

But what does "eat aloud" mean?

When you do something "aloud", it means you are making a specific effort to be heard.

To "read aloud" is to speak the words  as you look at them, as opposed to "reading silently", where you say the word in your head.

You don't "eat aloud". If you don't eat quietly you "eat loudly".

As for "it", yes, "it" is appropriate in this sentence, which should indeed be:

"I don't like it when people eat loudly."

Although it may be better to say "noisily" rather than "loudly", which makes the sound more emphatically inappropriate.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Please note the last sentence of my answer, where I make this point.

Comment: I don't think it's very helpful to learners to tell them that just because no-one talks about ***eating loud***, there's a hard-and-fast adjective/adverb distinction here (you've only to look at the usage chart for [*don't **talk** so **loud / loudly***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don%27t+talk+so+loud%2Cdon%27t+talk+so+loudly&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20talk%20so%20loud%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20talk%20so%20loudly%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20talk%20so%20loud%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20talk%20so%20loudly%3B%2Cc0)).

Comment: I'm afraid I am going to have to disagree with you there. Just because 99% of the population speaks ungrammatically because of appalling ignorance, that does not mean we should teach people genuinely trying to learn accurate usage that the rules of grammar do not really matter.

Comment: You're obviously an extreme prescriptivist! I'm pretty much 100% a [linguistic] *descriptivist* myself, so I'm almost inclined to say that once 51% of the population adopt a particular usage, *by definition* that becomes the "correct" form. Okay - maybe that's a bit *too* extreme - but certainly once we get anywhere near 2/3rds on one side and only 1/3rd on the other side, the democratic principle seems unassailable to me. And we should *definitely* forget about how Latin used to work, when looking at how English works today.

Answer (score 1):

It is not natural to use `either aloud or loud` in your sentence where loud is an adjective.

"Loudly" is associated with the meaning "in a way that makes much noise", whereas "aloud" can be used but in a different sense - not typically with the verb *"eat/chew." So the best choice would be "loudly."*

In my experience, *"it"* sounds perfectly idiomatic in British English, though that most native speakers of American English may drop it, especially in speech.

Comment: There is no hard-and-fast correlation between "loudly" and "making *too much* noise", "Loudly" itself is neutral in tone and whether the noise made is "too much" or not is not part of its meaning.